# Subscribing tags to get only website notifications

Tags: support, questions

How do I subscribe to tags and receive notifications on Stack Exchange's website only, and not on my mail-id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this Q&A on the mSO site: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254318/how-to-subscribe-to-tags, specifically this page: https://stackexchange.com/filters/71248/my-filter.